# How to speed up performance of taxonomy hierarchical select drupal

Tags: performance

I have a taxonomy that have **35(States)** -> **650(Districts)** -> **6500(Blocks)** -> **650000(Villages)** taxonomy terms using [hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)  module

when i filter it on my content type form then it's performance is very slow. so, i want to know that how to increase it's performance when filtering.

i have installed [taxonomy manager module](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) but we can't use it as CCK Field of Taxonomy Term.

Answer (score 1):

Using [High-performance JavaScript callback handler](https://www.drupal.org/project/js) will speed up it a bit while i recommend using [Simple hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) rather than Hierarchical Select , cause it is much faster in queries (off course less user friendly) .

this is the description [High-performance JavaScript callback handler](https://www.drupal.org/project/js) :

> JavaScript callback handler is an interim solution for high-performance server requests including (but not limited to) AHAH, AJAX, JSON, XML, etc.
>   This project targets module developers and provides a "bare bone" callback handler which is intended to be addressed by modules wanting to improve response times for specialized tasks.

Comment: i have tried it but it's working but not fully satisfied